# Make new folders in parent directory not in directory where script is located

Tags: powershell

I have been using this quite successfully until someone messed with the file.

So I need to hide the file or move it to a hidden folder.
The problem I have is it makes the new folders in the directory it resides in.

I would like it to make the new folders in the parent directory.

```
 ###Get the year entered by the user
$year = Read-Host "Please enter year"

$nextyear = [int]$year + 1

$yearfolder = "$year-$nextyear"

###Set the starting date
$startdate = [DateTime] "01 April $($year)"
$count = 1

###Set the file's path by combining the folder path and the filename
$filename = join-Path -Path (Get-location) -ChildPath "a.txt"

###Create folder based on the year entered by the user
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "$($yearfolder)"

###Change directory to the newly created folder
cd "$($yearfolder)"


While ( $count -lt 13)
{
    ###Create folders 
    $newfolder = "$($count.ToString('00')) - $($startdate.ToString('MMMM yyyy'))"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "$newfolder"

    #Copy file to new folder
    Copy-Item -Path $filename -Destination $newfolder

    #Add one month
    $startdate = $startdate.AddMonths(1)

    #Increment the counter
    $count = $count + 1

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relative paths.

So if your path is `"..\MyPath"` and you create that, it will be created one level higher and then as a sub path of that folder.

Similarly, if you specify: `"..\..\..\Folder\Another"` it will go 3 levels higher, then go into the folder Folder (that one must exist though) and then create Another.

Also similarly, you can use `"\Folder\MyFolder"` to create your folder in the root, then subfolder Folder, then create your MyFolder, and it will use the current drive. This way, your script can work on a thumb drive without it knowing what drive letter it has.

So with this in mind, you can simply use the following code:

```
$yearfolder = "..\$year-$nextyear"
```

Or if you want to be on the safe side:

```
$yearfolder = "..\$($year)-$($nextyear)"
```

Using $(...) basically allows you to put any command or variable inside a string.

For example this will not work:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -filter * | select -first 1

Write-host "We found $user.FullName"
```

But this will work:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -filter * | select -first 1

Write-host "We found $($user.FullName)"
```

Comment: Boom. And there it was done. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hi. If this solved your problem, feel free to accept this answer as answered. That way, others know you no longer need help.